# Test Vuex Action that Calls Getters and Mutations

Tags: vuex, vue-test-utils

What I would like to do is to test the following vuex action which calls a few mutations and getters. I can't tell if my issues cause of async/await issues or that I am not really calling/dispatching the action code.

#### Actions

```js
export const actions = {
async updateTaxOnLine({dispatch, commit}, {lineId}) {
        await commit('toggleTaxOnLine', {lineId});
        await dispatch('updateTaxOnAllLines');
    },
    async updateTaxOnAllLines({getters, commit}) {
        getters.receiptLines.forEach(l => {
            if (l.add_tax) {
                const tax = ((parseFloat(l.amount) / getters.taxLinesBaseAmount) * parseFloat(getters.receipt.tax)).toFixed(2);
                console.log(`Setting tax to line ${l.id} calculating (${l.amount} / ${getters.taxLinesBaseAmount}) * ${getters.receipt.tax} = ${tax}`)
                commit('setTaxOnLine', {lineId: l.id, tax: tax});
            } else {
                commit('setTaxOnLine', {lineId: l.id, tax: null});
            }
        });
    },
}
```

#### Test

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import {createLocalVue} from "@vue/test-utils";

import {actions, getters, mutations, state} from './index'


let store;

beforeEach(() => {
    createLocalVue().use(Vuex);
    store = new Vuex.Store({
        state,
        getters,
        mutations,
        actions,
    });
});


describe('store', () => {
    it('set tax on a line sets the amount correctly', async () => {
        store.replaceState({
            receipt: {
                "id": 28,
                "created": "2021-01-14T22:41:53.023594Z",
                "updated": "2021-06-06T01:52:11.092877Z",
                "user": null,
                "datetime": "2020-11-21T02:51:00Z",
                "subtotal": "96.29",
                "tax": "6.74",
                "amount": "103.03",
                "status": "CODING",
                "error_message": null,
                "lines": [
                    {
                        id: 355,
                        created: "2021-05-17T05:19:44.424661Z",
                        updated: "2021-06-05T21:10:04.856432Z",
                        entry_method: "AZURE_RECEIPT_AI",
                        quantity: "2.00",
                        unit_price: "2.99",
                        tax: null,
                        amount: "5.98",
                        personal: false,
                        add_tax: false,  // THIS line is TAXED
                    },
                ]
            }
        });
        await store.dispatch('toggleTaxOnLine', {lineId: 355});
        expect(store.getters.receipt.lines[0].add_tax).toBeTruthy();
        expect(store.getters.receipt.lines[0].tax).toEqual(6.74);
        expect(store.getters.taxLinesBaseAmount).toEqual(5.98);
    });
});
```

#### Mutations

```js
export const mutations = {
toggleTaxOnLine: (state, {lineId}) => {
        const foundLine = state.receipt.lines.find(l => l.id === lineId);
        foundLine.add_tax = !foundLine.add_tax;
    },
    setTaxOnLine: (state, {lineId, tax}) => {
        const foundLine = state.receipt.lines.find(l => l.id === lineId);
        foundLine.tax = tax;
    },
};
```

#### Getters

```js
export const getters = {
    receipt: state => state.receipt,
    taxLinesBaseAmount: (state, getters) => getters.receiptLines.reduce((accum, l) => {
        if (l.add_tax) {
            return parseFloat(l.amount) + parseFloat(accum);
        }
        return accum;
    }, 0),
};
```

The Error that I get is:

```
console.error
 
node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:499
    [vuex] unknown action type: toggleTaxOnLine
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't read the error message close enough. Basically I am calling dispatch on `'toggleTaxOnLine'` when I needed to either update the dispatch call to `'updateTaxOnLine'` or change the action to be `toggleTaxOnLine` I chose the former.